# Cannot get the max value in a SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to get the max id of a table in SQLite in Android. This is how I get it in the database helper:

```
public int getMaxIncrementation() {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String result = "0";
        try{
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(id) FROM " +TABLE_INCREMENTATION, new String[]{});
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(INCREMENTATION_ID));
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ex", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(result);
    };
```

This is how I created the table:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_INCREMENTATION = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_INCREMENTATION
            + "("
            + INCREMENTATION_DATEADDED + " TEXT,"
            + INCREMENTATION_DIRECTION + " INTEGER,"
            + INCREMENTATION_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + INCREMENTATION_USER + " TEXT"
            + ")";
```

This is the snapshot of my table with data in it:

[image]

On debugging, I always get this error:

> Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor
> is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, since you don't have in the query any `?` placeholders then you don't need to pass any parameters to the sql statement, so the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()` should be `null`.
Also you must give an alias to the column that your query returns and use it to get the returned value (you can't use `INCREMENTATION_ID` because it is not the name of the column returned):

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM " +TABLE_INCREMENTATION, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("maxid"));
```

Or if you don't use an alias then use `0` as there is only 1 column returned:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(id) FROM " +TABLE_INCREMENTATION, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    result = cursor.getString(0);
```